# ForEach-Object piped to CSV is only showing last element

Tags: powershell, foreach, pipe, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export to csv the scheduled tasks for multiple remote machines. I'm using a modified version of [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Scheduled-tasks-from-3a377294). I'm trying to export one csv per machine that lists all of the scheduled tasks. Currently my code just exports the last task for each machine.

```
foreach ($computerName in $computerNames) {
    $Schedule.connect($computerName) 
    $AllFolders = Get-AllTaskSubFolders

    foreach ($Folder in $AllFolders) {
        if ($Tasks = $Folder.GetTasks(0)) {
            $TASKS | % {[array]$results += $_}
            $Tasks | Foreach-Object {
                New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
                    'Name' = $_.name
                    'Path' = $_.path
                    'Server' = $computername
                } | Export-Csv $("C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\" + $computername + ".csv")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I've tried putting the Export-Csv at the end of each of the curly braces and none output what I want. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT
I'm not sure this fully addresses the issue, as some parts of the code seem weired to me such as `$tasks = $folder.GetTasks`. However OP title clearly says that the CSV is showing the last element meaning to me that his code mostly works except for the Export-CSV part.

`Export-Csv` expects an array as input, so the code below uses the elements in `$task` to generate the array of objects. `Select-Object` is there to decide in which order the properties are stored in the CSV.

Try this:

```
foreach ($computerName in $computerNames) {
    $Schedule.connect($computerName) 
    $AllFolders = Get-AllTaskSubFolders

    $result = @()
    foreach ($Folder in $AllFolders) {
        if ($Tasks = $Folder.GetTasks(0)) {
            $TASKS | % {[array]$results += $_}

            $Tasks | Foreach-Object {
                $result += New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
                    Name = $_.name;
                    Path = $_.path;
                    Server = $computername
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $result | select Name, Path, Server | Export-Csv $($exportPath + $computername + ".csv")
}
```

This new version saves results on a per computer basis.

Comment: Assuming this does address the issue however it would be worth it to the OP, and others, if you explain why this works.

Comment: I'm running this against 3 machines. The first exported 1 task, the second exported 5, and the third exported 0. However, I know the first has 215, the second has 224, and the third has 70.

Comment: OK, then you need to see how `$Tasks` is filled and if it has all the data.

Comment: I see you added some changes, let me incorporate them into my answer too

Comment: If I pipe this whole script to CSV and remove the Export-Csv from the script, all of the tasks displayed, just in one file.

Comment: Made a change that will allow saving results on a per computer basis.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing either $exportPath or $computername in your loop, so each time through your outer loop, the csv file is being overwritten. Also, this

```
if ($Tasks = $Folder.GetTasks(0)) {
```

may be wrong. If you're trying to determine if $Tasks is equal to $Folder.GetTasks(0), you'd need this:

```
if ($Tasks -eq $Folder.GetTasks(0)) {
```